# Object -> Edit / Change of position

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I've modeled an object, rigged the body and was going to rig the face when I noticed that when i change between "Object mode", "Edit mode" and "Pose mode", it changes position.In "Object mode" and "Pose mode" it is on 0,0,0 but when I change to "Edit mode" it suddenly moves out of location in all three axis.Attaching an image for better clarification.

Moving the object in "Object mode" to the position it is in "Edit mode" also changes it in that tab, and vice versa.How can I reset it so it stays on the supposed main location as it is in "Object mode"?[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you edit the pose of the armature rigged to a mesh, it shows the changes in the Object and Pose mode, while in Edit mode shows the original undeformed mesh. Could be that? Check by selecting all the bones in Pose Mode and Pose>Clear Transform>All, and look if it changes between modes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did that and although it all stays in the same position which was what I was looking for, they stay on the position it was in "Edit mode".
I would like to have my character aligned with all the axis.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank you for your help, I did that and although it all stays in the
>   same position which was what I was looking for, they stay on the
>   position it was in "Edit mode". I would like to have my character
>   aligned with all the axis. How can I do that?

You have to align it in Edit Mode.

Edit mode is like if it was more important than the other modes, it goes something like Edit Mode > Object Mode > Pose Mode. This is like this because in edit mode you have the information of the mesh, in object mode the information of where is the mesh (and it's rotation) and in pose mode you have the information about how is the mesh deformed.

So use blender with this hierarchy in mind and you will ready to go.

Comment: Hmmm okay :) 
In "Edit mode" I select the armature and move it around but the mesh doesn't follow, when I go back to "Object mode" the position of the armature is changed aswell with the mesh staying on the same place it was, misaligning my armature>mesh.
What is the correct way to fix this? 
Do I need to rig the character again?

Comment: First move the Mesh in Edit mode to the location you want. Then move the armature in Edit mode to match the mesh. No need to re-rig or re-skin.

Comment: Thank you Mike!